# Why is replace() not working in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, escaping

I have some data I'm handling in Node.js and I need to replace the ampersands with the escape key. I have this code:

```
let newValue = data;
for (label in labelData.data) {
    let key = "Label " + label;
     newValue = newValue.replace(key, labelData.data[label]);

}
let noAmpersands = newValue.replace('&', '&amp;');
console.log(noAmpersands);
```

This code replaces placeholders in an SVG, but obviously the ampersands needed to be replaced with their escape character. However. this logs out the value without the ampersands replaced. For example, this:

```
<g transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 -865.665 -1513.81)">
 <text x="3000" y="3750" id="text4790-27" class="fil1 fnt0" text-anchor="middle">EthCAN 3 &</text>
```

should be

```
<g transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 -865.665 -1513.81)">
 <text x="3000" y="3750" id="text4790-27" class="fil1 fnt0" text-anchor="middle">EthCAN 3 &amp;</text>
```

What's going on?

Comment: Please provide some input and the expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Your end goal here is to encode [HTML entities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encodings_in_HTML), There are various online articles and answers on how to achieve that. just [google](https://www.google.com/search?q=encode%20html%20entities%20javascript)

If you just want to replace the `&`:
**Assuming** that `newVlaue` is a `string`

your code: `newValue.replace('&', '&amp;');` will only replace the first occurrence and not all occurrences. to replace all occurrences, use: `newValue.replace(/&/g, '&amp;');`